# SQL - CROSS APPLY not working properly

Tags: sql, sql-server, cross-apply

I think I'm losing my mind here. I try to update a specific subset of `Table1`. Let's say the `SELECT` from `Table1` returns 1 million rows. For each of these rows, I want to cross apply a specific calculated sum from `Table2`.

I know for a fact that not all rows in `Table1` can be joined to `Table2` with the conditions in the `CROSS APPLY` part.

The update still says 1,000,000 row(s) affected. After this I got suspicious and added the '1 = 0' condition to the `CROSS APPLY` so it could never return a row.

But it still updates all rows in `Table1`?

```
UPDATE T1
SET T1.Field1 = T2.SumField
FROM
    (
        SELECT *
        FROM Table1
        WHERE ....
    ) T1
CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT SUM(Field1) SumField
        FROM Table2
        WHERE [A lot of Fields] = [Some Values from T1]
        AND 1 = 0 -- !!!
    ) T2
```

Does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: I'm not sure why you're using `CROSS APPLY` for this, what's wrong with an `INNER` or a `LEFT JOIN` here? I'd say all your `WHERE 1 =0` did is return a NULL...

Comment: Microsoft will not feel good about your title. :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second query is not null set - it returns one value NULL which is joined with result.

```
UPDATE T1
SET T1.Field1 = T2.SumField
FROM
       (
        SELECT *
        FROM Table1
        WHERE ....
    ) T1
CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT Field1 SumField
        FROM Table2
        WHERE [A lot of Fields] = [Some Values from T1]
        AND 1 = 0 -- !!!
    ) T2
```

you will get 0 rows affected (notice missing SUM)

Comment: Yes, you are right. It returns a NULL column if I use the SUM aggregate. Thank you, this helped restore my sanity :)